# Get timestamp of a collection item in CQL / Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql

I know I can use `writetime()` to get the internal timestamp for a column, but is it possible to get the timestamp for a particular item in a collection (like a list)?  My understanding is that collection items are internally stored as individual columns, so it seems like they should have individual timestamps.

Answer (score 2):

The individual columns within a collection do indeed have individual timestamps. You can see this by examining the SSTable directly using the sstable2json function.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
user_id text,
emails set<text>,
first_name text,
last_name text,
PRIMARY KEY ((user_id))
)

INSERT INTO users (user_id, first_name, last_name, emails)
   VALUES('frodo', 'Frodo', 'Baggins', {'f@baggins.com', 'baggins@gmail.com'});

UPDATE users
   SET emails = emails + {'fb@friendsofmordor.org'} WHERE user_id = 'frodo';
```

Then the SSTable looks like this:

```
[
{"key": "66726f646f","columns": [["","",1444170199819000],
["emails","emails:!",1444170199818999,"t",1444170199], 
["emails:62616767696e7340676d61696c2e636f6d","",1444170199819000],  
["emails:664062616767696e732e636f6d","",1444170199819000], 
["emails:666240667269656e64736f666d6f72646f722e6f7267","",1444170213268000], 
["first_name","Frodo",1444170199819000], 
["last_name","Baggins",1444170199819000]]}
]
```

You can see the 3 entries in emails corresponding to timestamps 1444170199819000, 1444170199819000 and 1444170213268000.

However it seems like its not possible to return these through CQL. You won't be able to return individual columns from the set, but it would be reasonable to return the timestamps along with the values for all of the entries in the set, however I can't find any documentation on how to do this so it doesn't look like its supported.

Answer (score 1):

Collection elements have their own timestamps, but it is impossible to get those timestamps using CQL. See corresponding Jira ticket to support this functionality: [CASSANDRA-8877](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8877).